# Wigner semicircle law and random measures

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, random-matrices

**tl;dr:** the proof of the Wigner semicircle law seems to confuse measures with random measures. I do not understand why. Scroll down until '**QUESTION**' if you are fine with the theoretical stuff.

---

T. Tao in his *Topics in Random Matrix Theory* defines the (normalized) *empirical spectral distribution* (*ESD*) of a *Wigner Hermitian matrix ensamble* $M_n = ( \xi_{ij} )_{1 \le i,j \le n} $ as $$\mu_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} M_n} := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n \delta_{\lambda_j (M_n)/\sqrt{n}} $$where $\lambda_1(M_n) \le \dots \le \lambda_n(M_n) $ are the real eigenvalues of $M_n$ (counting multiplicity). Now the object $\mu_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} M_n}$ is not a "usual" measure but, as Tao himself points out, a *random measure*, i.e. a random variable taking values in the space $\text{Pr}(\mathbb{R})$ (probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$ [with the vague topology](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/books/topics-in-random-matrix-theory/)). To clarify this concept, I think that the definition given in the book by Klenke (*Probability Theory - A comprehensive course*) is enlightening: [image]

If I understand correctly the definition in Klenke "applied" to the ESD situation, what we have is a map from some probability space with values in $\text{Pr}(\mathbb{R})$ that should be something like $$ \mathbf{\omega}=(\omega_1, \dots, \omega_{n^2}) \mapsto \mu_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} M_n (\mathbf{\omega}) };  $$i.e., in my understanding, when a $\omega$ is picked, $M_n$ "collapses" to a matrix $M_n(\omega)$  (in the sense of Linear Algebra) and then $\mu_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} M_n(\omega)}$ becomes a probability measure. Am I interpreting things correctly so far?

The modes of convergence only sketched by Tao are clarified in the book by Kallenberg (*Random Measures, Theory and Applications*):

[image]

---

**QUESTION**: what puzzles me is in the actual proof of the Wigner semicircle law. In the book of Tao such proof is broken down in a certain number of exercises and he refers to the book by Bai and Silverstein (*Spectral Analysis for Large Dimensional Random Matrices*) for additional details. Their proof uses the [Carleman's condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleman%27s_condition)... this Carleman condition is nonetheless about *measures* and not *random measures*. There seem to be in this setting a confusion between the two objects; the whole moment method seems to be developed treating $\mu_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} M_n}$ as *deterministic* objects, while they are not (?). I expected to see something like [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00535262). The book by Zeitouni does pretty much the same, thus there must be something that I miss. What?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The moment method comes with a variance estimate. That is, you show  that the $k$th moment  converges in probability, for each $k$ (the k-th moment is a random object, it is the kth moment of the empirical distribution). From this fact, together with a-priori estimates on the total mass outside a compact, the convergence of the empirical measure, integrated again bounded continuous test functions (which gives you a random variable), follows. This is (slightly stronger) than the vp convergence you quate.

Comment: @oferzeitouni thank you for your comment. I also read the first pages of your book and I have now a better grasp of what is going on. My doubt is somehow solved by **Lemma 2.1.7**; what I did not understand was how to apply the classical Carleman's condition as stated in the Wiki page to the sequence in your book called $\langle L_N, x^k \rangle $. The randomness of $\langle L_N, x^k \rangle $, which is a random variable, did not fit the hypothesis; that's why I asked if there was some "non-deterministic" Carleman going on behined the scenes.

Comment: Carleman criterion is an overkill, since the limit here is compactly supported, and such measures are determined by their moments.